# Node size proportional to number of children in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I created this click-expand-collapse network -http://jsfiddle.net/5Lv8gkqv/

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root = {
 "name": "Chocolate", "tag":"class",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Wafer", "tag":"subclass",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "Nestle", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "KitKat", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },

  {
   "name": "White", "tag":"subclass",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "Nestle", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Milkybar", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },

    {
   "name": "Caramel", "tag":"subclass",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "Nestle", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BarOne", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },    
    {
   "name": "Milk", "tag":"subclass",
   "children": [
    {
      "name": "Nestle", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Nestle Milk", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    },  {
      "name": "Cadbury", "tag":"company",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Dairy Milk", "tag":"product"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }




 ]
};

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.05)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

flatten(root); //to set ids
setParents(root, null);
collapseAll(root);
root.children = root._children;
root._children = null;
update();

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
      : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
      : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
      collapseAll(d);
  } else {
      if (d._parent){
          d._parent.children.forEach(function(e){
              if (e != d){
                  collapseAll(e);
              }
          });
      }
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}

function collapseAll(d){
    if (d.children){
        d.children.forEach(collapseAll);
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    }
    else if (d._childred){
        d._children.forEach(collapseAll);
    }
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}

function setParents(d, p){
    d._parent = p;
  if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(function(e){ setParents(e,d);});
  } else if (d._children) {
      d._children.forEach(function(e){ setParents(e,d);});
  }
}
```

The thing now is that I was wondering if its possible to have node-size proportional to the number of children. So the parent node will be the biggest circle and the leaf node will be the smallest, while the intermediate node-size will be dependent on the number of children each have.

Comment: If you're only looking for immediate children, you just need to get `d.children.length` when setting the radius: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lv8gkqv/1/

Answer (score 8):

You can use `d3.scale.linear` for calculating radius of nodes proportional to the number of children. `d3.scale` also helps to find a radius in between a range. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lv8gkqv/2/)

```
 var minRadius = 10;
 var maxRadius = 15;
 var scale = d3.scale.linear().range([minRadius,maxRadius]);
 nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { 
        if(d.children)
            return scale(d.children.length);
        else if(d._children)
            return scale(d._children.length);
        else
            return minRadius;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**: Now takes into account children that aren't shown, using the idea from @Gilsha's answer.

---

Sure, you can set each `<circle>`'s radius proportional to the number of children they have:

```
node.select("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d){
         var numKids = 0;
         if (d.children) numKids += d.children.length;
         if (d._children) numKids += d._children.length;
         return 10 * (numKids + 1);
})
```

where `r` is some radius. Using `r=10` and toggling on the `"wafer"` node, you get this:
[image]

Comment: thats working fine but Ive to click on "wafer" in order to make its size come up proportional to its number of children. By default Chocolate comes up biggest, whereas its 4 kids are coming same size. Which shudnt happen coz "Milk" has two children and thus "milk" shud be coming up second largest node-size. Hope you got the idea

Answer (score 1):

For a complete solution, you'll actually want to use a recursive function to first calculate the *total* children (not just first-level children) of each node. For example:

```
var bubble_up_total_children = function(node) {
  var child, _i, _len, _ref;
  if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
    _ref = node.children;
    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      child = _ref[_i];
      bubble_up_total_children(child);
    }
    node.total_children = node.children.length + node.children.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.total_children + b.total_children;
    });
  } else {
    node.total_children = 0;
  }
};

bubble_up_total_children(root);
```

From there you can now use d3.scale as already documented in @Gilsha's answer to calculate size based on the new `total_children` attribute on each node.

Comment: Good insight that was

Comment: Recursive algorithms [solve everything](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zRjU038vl0)!