# I want to change node size based on degree of node in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, social-networking

I am displaying social network graph based on facebook data its working fine.But now i want that size of node should change on basis of degree.
Can someone help me with this.
Thanku

Comment: Are you using circles to represent nodes? If so, change radius of nodes based on degree. You can use d3 scale for better usability. Refer my answer for a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887143/node-size-proportional-to-number-of-children-in-d3)

Comment: I tried `.attr("r",function(d){return d.degree;});` but it didn't work

Comment: What are the possible values for `degree`? You should limit the radius values within a range. Check if the values you set as radius are valid.